# How do I change my button color and text in Ionic Framework?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So far I have the color change working but I need the text too.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonCtrl" class="padding">
<button class="button button-block" ng-click="button.clicked=!button.clicked" ng-class="button.clicked?'button-assertive':'button-positive'">
</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('ButtonCtrl',function($scope) {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops, just found this way and it works! Thank you guys.

```
<span ng-if="!button.clicked">Check-In</span>
<span ng-if="button.clicked">Check-Out</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to color the text, just add:

```
button{
   color: blue;
}
```

but this will be applied to all button text, if you just want change one button, add an 'id' to this button, and add:

```
 #id{
  color: blue;
}
```

in your case, should be:

```
.button-assertive{
       color: blue;
    }
.button-positive{
        color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just like this:

```
<button ... style="background-color: #ff0000;"></button>
```

Could you be more specific? What color do you want to change. Background or font color?

If you need the color binded to your controller then this approach is possible the best one:

```
<button ... ng-style="ctrl.color"></button>
```